# How to add Contols on runtime in Titanium alloy

Tags: android, sqlite, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am developing an mobile app in Titanium alloy to place order.
In that I am saving user place order in sqlite database and remote server.
when user try to place order then i have to show previously place order from sqlite database.
for that i have did the fallowing code

XML file

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <View>
            <ScrollView id="PreOrders">

            </ScrollView>
            <TextArea id="txtTextOrder"></TextArea>
            <Button id="btnSend" onClick="SendTextOrder">Send</Button>>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

in js file i have write a function to add the previous orders

```
(function AddPreOrder(){
    var db = Ti.Database.open('Database\LaafoodAppDb'); 
    var OrderDetails = db.execute('SELECT * FROM Text_Orders'); 
    while (OrderDetails.isValidRow())
    {
        var DivOrder=Ti.UI.createView({
            borderColor:'red',
            width:'70%',
            height:'Auto',
        });
        var Order=Ti.UI.createLabel();
        Order.text=OrderDetails.fieldByName('Order');
        DivOrder.add(Order);
        $.PreOrders.add(DivOrder);          
        OrderDetails.next();
    }   
    db.close(); 
})();
```

but its not adding order to activity. I am very new to mobile app development please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should check that data is present in database table or not.....then you should use Ti.UI.SIZE to set DivOrder's height instead of auto... and be sure that you set layout to vertical or horizontal for scrollview . If you did not set then set it first otherwise all the views are overlaped each other.